# Slang words my parents used

Tags: word-meaning, swearwords

When I was growing up, my parents used a lot of Italian slang words. One I remember sounded like "Ah Sorda", but I never knew what it was. Another was "jisu greest", (I know that one) followed by something like "Engrojuda". So it was "Jisu Greest Engrojuda". Can you help me with these two words?

Comment: Where do your parents come from? I mean, what region of Italy?

Comment: Not exactly sure, I think around Monte Casino it's definitely slang terms

Comment: *jisu greest* is, I think, *Gisù Crist* (Jesus Christ in slang)

Comment: *Engrojuda* may be *'n croce*, (on the cross), so that the phrase was *Gisù Crist' 'n croce* (Jesus Christ on the cross), it is a common expression in South Italy.

Comment: If they were of Naples, I would say that Ah Sorda could be *'A ciorta*, ( *la sorte* in Italian, the fate), but in Montecassino I don't know if it is the same.

Comment: You may have it with Jesus Christ on the cross. I'm guessing monte Casino area because they seemed to talk about that area quite a bit.

Comment: *Gisù Crist' 'n croce* is very common and I think that in the area of Montecassino should be the same.

Comment: “Cassino”, not “Casino”, also since “casino”, while literally “small house”, used to be a euphemism for “brothel” and hence “chaos, mess”.

Comment: Thank you both.

Comment: DaG. I removed my other post. Hope you are pleased.

Answer (score 4):

"Ah Sorda" is probably *assòr't* (*assòreta*, *a sòreta*), Southern Italian for "(to) your sister". Definitely *not* a nice thing to say to anyone, on par with *ammamm't* "(to) your mother".

*Jisu Greest Engrojuda* is almost certainly *gisu-grist-in-groce* (standard *Gesù Cristo in croce*, meaning *Jesus Christ on the Cross*).

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling that one wasn't a nice thing to say, but never knew the words said after Gisu Greest. So my folks probably were not from Monte Casino then. Still learning about my ancestry

Comment: That would be Monte Cassino with two "s"s -- otherwise it might sound like *mount Brothel*. Montecassino is halfway between Rome and Neaples, and they speak umbro-marquesan, where "a soreta" is documented [ https://dialettitaliani.it/wiki/Soreta_(Cassino) ].